# Microsoft graph drive item webUrl does not provide same viewing capability as OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The microsoft graph drive item webUrl give the view url of the drive item according to the documentation:
"URL that displays the resource in the browser. Read-only."

We're finding that the url returned for images and videos do one of two things:

- returns an html page with either an img or video tag that will display/play the file
- download the file

For example, avi files get downloaded but if we go to OneDrive and do 'preview' then a viewer is brought up that plays the video.

Is there any way to get this view url through api rather than what the webUrl gives. The url seems to be in a form like:
https://jostledev-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxx/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?FolderCTID=yyy&id=%2Fpersonal%2Fxxx%2FDocuments%2FJostle%20Storage%2FWildlife%2Ewmv&parent=%2Fpersonal%2Fxxx%2FDocuments%2FJostle%20Storage

Answer (score 0):

Indeed [`DriveItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0) `webUrl` property returns a *raw a url to asset* in One Drive.

To return the link to page, [Create a sharing link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0) endpoint could be utilized, for example the request:

```
POST /me/drive/items/{item-id}/createLink
Content-type: application/json

{
  "type": "view",
  "scope": "anonymous"
}
```

should return the following response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#permission",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.permission",
    "id": "34e2cb9c-bab6-4a60-b48b-f274af531ba5",
    "roles": [
        "read"
    ],
    "link": {
        "scope": "anonymous",
        "type": "view",
        "webUrl": "https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/jdoe_contoso_onmicrosoft_com/EXU29gb_xaZCjCNqN7F0_AMBqt9rXdrE_E6GLDoSNAFOFg"
    }
}
```

where `link.webUrl` property contains link of page.

**Update**

Another option would be to construct page url from `DriveItem.webUrl` property, for example:

```
function createPageLink(webUrl){
   const oneDriveUrl = webUrl.substr(0,webUrl.indexOf('onmicrosoft_com') + 'onmicrosoft_com'.length);
   var relUrl = webUrl.substr(webUrl.indexOf('/personal'))
   const parentUrl = relUrl.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/');
   return `${oneDriveUrl}/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?id=${relUrl}&parent=${parentUrl}`;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. We know about the sharing link and preview (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-preview?view=graph-rest-1.0) and neither work for us as, we require that the access control on the url be the same as what it is for the underlying file. In the case of sharing link, the scope is either anonymous or organization which is broader than who the underlying file is shared to.

Comment: @user1452215, the answer has been updated (update section)